# How to preserve newlines while reading a file using stream - java 8

Tags: java, java-8, newline, java-stream, replaceall

```
      try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(targetFile)) {  
     List<String> replacedContent = lines.map(line ->  
                                       StringUtils.replaceEach(line,keys, values))
                                       .parallel()
                                       .collect(Collectors.toList());
    Files.write(targetFile, replacedContent);
}
```

I'm trying to replace multiple text patterns in each line of the file. But I'm observing that "\r\n"(byte equivalent 10 and 13) is being replaced with just "\r"(just 10) and my comparison tests are failing.

I want to preserve the newlines as they are in the input file and don't want java to touch them. Could anyone suggest if there is a way to do this without having to use a separate default replacement for "\r\n".

Comment: Sorry for missing that. Just added.

Comment: Just removed the replaceEach to isolate the issue and its the Files.line() which seems to be doing this.

Comment: Where is the replace happening? The code you pasted created a List of String, it does not have any newline character.

Comment: ` StringUtils.replaceEach()` does the replacement on each `line` where `keys` are found. `keys` are replaced with `values`. and these `line`s are from a file - `targetFile`. I generate a list of strings and write them all to a file.

Comment: You are saying that “`"\r\n"` … is being replaced with just `"\r"`”. The question is where that does happen as streams don't do that. The string produced by `Files.lines` don’t have any line breaks at all.

Comment: Got it. I have to add them explicitly. Problem is I'm writing the list to the file and they don't end with newline as streams don't  include them for me.

Comment: What operating system are you running on?

Comment: I have a hypothesis: `Files.write()` adds "end of line" characters as it writes each "line" from the given list. The precise "end of line" sequence used is dependent on the OS you are using. Since you see only `"\r"`, I guess you are on Mac OS.

Comment: [`Files.write`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#write-java.nio.file.Path-java.lang.Iterable-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-) can write a list of strings as lines and will add the system specific line break for each line. On Windows, it should be the desired `\r\n` sequence.

Comment: Which version of Windows?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is that `Files.lines()` is implemented on top of `BufferedReader.readLine()`, which reads a line up until the line terminator and throws it away. Then, when you write the lines with something like `Files.write()`, this supplies the system-specific line terminator after each line, which might differ from the line terminator that was read in.

If you really want to preserve the line terminators exactly as they are, even if they're a mixture of different line terminators, you could use a regex and `Scanner` for that.

First define a pattern that matches a line including the valid line terminators or EOF:

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile(".*\\R|.+\\z");
```

The `\\R` is a special linebreak matcher that matches the usual line terminators plus a few Unicode line terminators that I've never heard of. :-) You could use something like `(\\r\\n|\\r|\\n)` if you want just the usual **CRLF**, **CR**, or **LF** terminators.

You have to include `.+\\z` in order to match a potential last "line" in the file that doesn't have a line terminator. Make sure the regex always matches at least one character so that no match will be found when the Scanner reaches the end of the file.

Then, read lines using a `Scanner` until it returns `null`:

```
try (Scanner in = new Scanner(Paths.get(INFILE), "UTF-8")) {
    String line;
    while ((line = in.findWithinHorizon(pat, 0)) != null) {
        // Process the line, then write the output using something like
        // FileWriter.write(String) that doesn't add another line terminator.
    }
}
```

Comment: Stuart and others, I think I can't use scanner with multithreaded program right? Is there any other way to achieve this for multithreaded programs?

Comment: @AshwiniR You can use a single `Scanner` instance from only one thread at a time in a multithreaded program. Multiple threads can use different `Scanner` instances, as long as no two threads operate on the same instance. If you want to process lines from a single file in parallel, this is difficult, since reading the file and writing the output is sequential. It's probably only worth running in parallel if there is a large amount of computation for each line.

Comment: Thanks Stuart. I create a `Scanner` instance within a thread. This instance reads all the lines one by one, creates a list of lines and closes the scanner. Any other thread running in parallel to this thread'll have its own instance of `Scanner`. So I don't need to worry about `Scanner` being thread-unsafe or about synchronizing the method in which I use `Scanner` right?

Comment: Processing many lines at a time: I create an array of callables (each callable is executed by one thread to process a set of lines at a time) & then do invokeAll() on this array. Results will be collected in an array so this maintains the order and I can use it to write. This worked fine in my testing. Do you see any issues with the approach?

Answer (score 3):

The lines in your stream do not include any newline character.

It would be nice if the method documentation for `Files.lines()` mentioned this. However, if you follow the implementation, it eventually leads to `BufferedReader.readLine()`. That method is documented to return the contents of the line, [not including any line-termination characters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine--).

You can add a newline character to the lines when you write them.

**A system-dependent line separator** is used by the [`Files.write()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#write-java.nio.file.Path-java.lang.Iterable-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-) method you're calling, as [documented in its sibling](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#write-java.nio.file.Path-java.lang.Iterable-java.nio.charset.Charset-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-). You can also get this system-dependent line separator with [`System.lineSeparator()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator--).

**If you want a different line separator, and know what it is,** you can specify it. For example:

```
    try ( PrintStream out = new PrintStream( Files.newOutputStream( targetFile ))) 
    {
        lines.forEach( line -> out.print( line + "\r\n") );
    }
```

**If you want the original file's line separators,** you can't rely only on a method that strips those out. Options include:

- Reading the first line separator, and guessing that it's consistent throughout the file. This allows you to continue to use `Files.lines()` to read the lines.
- Use an API that allows you to get lines with their separators.
- Read character-by-character, rather than line-by-line, so that you can get the line separators.

**WARNING:** Your code reads and writes from the same file. You could lose your original data due to abnormal termination or bugs.

Comment: It appears that `Files.write()` adds the "end of line" sequence as it writes each line in the given list.

Comment: I think the Files.write is adding them but its adding only "\r" only. My input file has "\r\n".  I dont see a way to change this in Files.write() !!

Comment: @AshwiniR - You might be able to do that by setting the `line.separator` property, but that hack affects the entire process. Using a mechanism other than `Files.write()` may be preferable. See an example in the edited text above. Also note the warning added after your comment.